# List of minimal pairs from a pair of lists

Tags: python, algorithm

Given two lists of integers, generate the shortest list of pairs where every value in both lists is present. The first of each pair must be a value from the first list, and the second of each pair must be a value from the second list. The first of each pair must be less than the second of the pair.

A simple `zip` will not work if the lists are different lengths, or if the same integer exists at the same position in each list.

```
def gen_min_pairs(uplist, downlist):
    for pair in zip(uplist, downlist):
        yield pair
```

Here is what I can come up with so far:

```
def gen_min_pairs(uplist, downlist):
    up_gen = iter(uplist)
    down_gen = iter(downlist)

    last_up = None
    last_down = None

    while True:
        next_out = next(up_gen, last_up)
        next_down = next(down_gen, last_down)

        if (next_up == last_up and
            next_down == last_down):
            return

        while not next_up < next_down:
            next_down = next(down_gen, None)
            if next_down is None:
                return
        yield next_up, next_down

        last_up = next_up
        last_down = next_down
```

And here is a simple test routine:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pprint import pprint

    datalist = [
        {
            'up': [1,7,8],
            'down': [6,7,13]
        },
        {
            'up': [1,13,15,16],
            'down': [6,7,15]
        }
    ]

    for dates in datalist:    
        min_pairs = [pair for pair in
                     gen_min_pairs(dates['up'], dates['down'])]
        pprint(min_pairs)
```

The program produces the expect output for the first set of dates, but fails for the second.

Expected:

```
[(1, 6), (7, 13), (8, 13)]
[(1, 6), (1, 7), (13, 15)]
```

Actual:

```
[(1, 6), (7, 13), (8, 13)]
[(1, 6), (13, 15)]
```

I think this can be done while only looking at each element of each list once, so in the complexity `O(len(up) + len(down))`. I think it depends on the number elements unique to each list.

EDIT: I should add that we can expect these lists to be sorted with the smallest integer first.

EDIT: `uplist` and `downlist` were just arbitrary names. Less confusing arbitrary ones might be `A` and `B`.

Also, here is a more robust test routine:

```
from random import uniform, sample
from pprint import pprint

def random_sorted_sample(maxsize=6, pop=31):
    size = int(round(uniform(1,maxsize)))
    li = sample(xrange(1,pop), size)
    return sorted(li)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = random_sorted_sample()
    B = random_sorted_sample()

    min_pairs = list(gen_min_pairs(A, B))

    pprint(A)
    pprint(B)
    pprint(min_pairs)
```

This generates random realistic inputs, calculates the output, and displays all three lists. Here is an example of what a correct implementation would produce:

```
[11, 13]
[1, 13, 28]
[(11, 13), (13, 28)]

[5, 15, 24, 25]
[3, 13, 21, 22]
[(5, 13), (15, 21), (15, 22)]

[3, 28]
[4, 6, 15, 16, 30]
[(3, 4), (3, 6), (3, 15), (3, 16), (28, 30)]

[2, 5, 20, 24, 26]
[8, 12, 16, 21, 23, 28]
[(2, 8), (5, 12), (5, 16), (20, 21), (20, 23), (24, 28), (26, 28)]

[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2]
[]
```

Comment: What do you want it to do when it uses (1,6) and goes to 7, should it be (7,13) or should it be (7, None).

Comment: Do you mean for the first set of test data or the second? The output for the first set of data is fine; if the pair `(7,13)` were replaced with the pair `(1,7)` it would still be fine. The output for the second set is wrong because `7` is not present in any pair. The only valid pair that could contain it is `(1,7)`. `None` should never appear in a pair.

Comment: The second expected list seems to violate the criteria.  (13,15)?  Where is 16?

Comment: `16` should not appear in any pair for the second set of data because there is no element in the downlist that is greater than it. `pair[0] < pair[1]` for every pair generated.

Comment: Why is `(1, 7)` not an expected answer in the first example?  I think I don't understand the requirements at all.

Comment: And why is `(13, 15)` an expected answer in the second example?  15 is not an element of the second list.

Comment: @Sven: `[(1, 6), (1, 7), (8, 13)]` and `[(1, 6), (7, 13), (8, 13)]` would both be valid outputs for the first data set. But to include both `(1, 7)` and `(7, 13)` in the output list would mean that the list is not the shortest possible list of tuples covering all values in each list.

Comment: @Sven: And as for the second data set, I made a typo! This has been fixed now :) `15` should appear in the downlist instead of `13`.

Answer (score 1):

I had many ideas to solve this (see edit history ;-/) but none of them quite worked out or did it in linear time. It took me a while to see it, but I had [a similar problem before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368802/split-a-list-of-dates-by-another-list-of-dates) so I really wanted to figure this out ;-)

Anyways, in the end the solution came when I gave up on doing it directly and started drawing graphs about the matchings. I think your first list simply defines intervals and you're looking for the items that fall into them:

```
def intervals(seq):
    seq = iter(seq)
    current = next(seq)
    for s in seq:
        yield current,s
        current = s
    yield s, float("inf")

def gen_min_pairs( fst, snd):
    snd = iter(snd)
    s = next(snd)
    for low, up in intervals(fst):
        while True:
            # does it fall in the current interval
            if low < s <= up:
                yield low, s
                # try with the next
                s = next(snd)
            else:
                # nothing in this interval, go to the next
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

zip_longest is called izip_longest in python 2.x.

```
import itertools    

def MinPairs(up,down):
    if not (up or down):
        return []
    up=list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x:x<down[-1],up))
    if not up:
        return []
    down=list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x:x<up[0],down))
    if not down:
        return []
    for i in range(min(len(up),len(down))):
        if up[i]>=down[i]:
            up.insert(i,up[i-1])
    return tuple(itertools.zip_longest(up,down,fillvalue=(up,down)[len(up)>len(down)][-1]))
```

Comment: Please see my second edit, where I have clarified what I expect of the the fucntion: your implementation returns `None` for the first two sample inputs where it should return a non-empty list. For the third sample, your output is correct. Also, you can assume the lists are sorted. If there are no possible pairs, an empty list should be returned.

Comment: Ok! that's the finally version, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

While not a complete answers (i.e. no code), have you tried looking at the numpy "where" module?

Comment: I haven't used numpy before. I will look at it, and will be grateful if this can solve my problem. But I would prefer to require only the standard library.